# How to create .tsv file in databricks(scala, python and etc.)

Tags: python, scala, databricks, azure-databricks

Please let me know how to create .tsv file in databricks code(scala, python).

ex: Example for .csv file creation.

%scala

val df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM Employee")

df.write.format("csv").option("header",true).option("inferSchema",true).option("delimiter","\t").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).save(destinationFilePath)

Answer (score 0):

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

```
object Test1 {

  case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").appName("test").getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._

    val ds = Seq(Person("eiffel", 23), Person("eiffel", 24)).toDS()
    // val ds = spark.sql("select * from person")
    ds.repartition(1).write.csv("file:///home/eiffel/csv")
  }
}
```